# Best way to connect Cloud SQL via connection pooling in GAE Flex

Tags: java, sql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I'm using Hibernate v5 in combination with GAE Flexible environment and Cloud SQL.

Everything works fine, but when an instance is waken up or after some cold time(no request served), it takes a long time to connect to the database (up to 8s) while the execution of query only takes in ms. Also it creates **serviceRegistry** again and again.

Can anyone please suggest what is best approach to connect with Cloud SQL avoiding higher latency in gaining connection.

PS: I am using cp30 for connection pooling.

Logs from app engine:

[image]

[image]
HibernateUtil Config:

```
        props.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "validate");
        props.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect");
        props.put("hibernate.generate_statistics", "true");
        props.put("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache", "true");
        props.put("hibernate.transaction.coordinator_class", "org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory");
        props.put("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class", "org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory");
        props.put("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", "true");

        props.put("connection.provider_class", "org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider");
        props.put("hibernate.c3p0.min_size", "40");
        props.put("hibernate.c3p0.max_size", "250");
        props.put("hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment", "1");
        props.put("hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckin", "true");
        props.put("hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period", "300");
        props.put("hibernate.c3p0.maxIdleTimeExcessConnections", "240");
        props.put("hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery", "SELECT 1");
         ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
        System.out.println("Hibernate Java Config serviceRegistry created");

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

        return sessionFactory;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are using [manual scaling](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/an-overview-of-app-engine#instance_scaling), your instances are often terminated and restarted. The instances have to reload all the libraries and configurations when they start so it's expected behavior for it to take longer.

There are two easy options for your use case:

1) Use a [Compute Engine instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/), which allows you to load your code, libraries and configuration and it's a dedicated VM that will continue to serve your requests and it doesn't "scale down" (terminated). This is definitely the safest method.

2) Use [manual scaling](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/an-overview-of-app-engine#instance_scaling) to scale your App Engine Flex app. This is almost as effective as the first option, but instances can still be restarted if they were unhealthy. In which case, make sure you have [health check](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/how-instances-are-managed#health_checking) setup to heal your instances if something happens. This will keep them alive and working as much as possible.

Comment: Thanks for answer @ying-li. Is there any way to connect to database as soon as an instance is started.

Comment: Are you talking about with automatic scaling or manual scaling? With automatic scaling, the instance is started when a request comes in, that's why there's always a loading time. If you are talking about manual scaling, then the instance is always ready and when it request comes in, it should automatically be processed.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "an instance is waken up" as an instance is either alive or dead. What it does when idle depends on your [scaling settings in the app.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#services), which is either to die or stay idling.

I think the creation of sessionFactory is the cause of the delay. This is a costly process due to Session factory encapsulating session object, connections, Hibernate properties caching and mappings.

I'm curious to see what happens if you reuse the sessionFactory (as per the example shamelessly stolen from [here](http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/building-hibernate-sessionfactory-from-service-registry)):

```
package net.codejava.hibernate;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;

public class HibernateUtil {
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if (sessionFactory == null) {
            // loads configuration and mappings
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry
                = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                    .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();

            // builds a session factory from the service registry
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);           
        }

        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

As you didn't provide the full code you'll have to adapt this example to your own situation.

Comment: **"an instance is waken up"** means when a new instance is created by Google to serve the traffic, post minimum number of instances.